# Logging in Spring initialization

Tags: java, spring, logging

I am initializing Spring in a web application using the ContextLoaderListener in web.xml. While initializing the context I see only [INFO] messages. How can I enable [DEBUG]?

The web app uses logback which is properly configured with [DEBUG] enabled in the root looger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring uses commons-logging underneath and delegates all logging to it. Since you are using logback include the [jcl-over-slf4j.jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22jcl-over-slf4j%22) in your project to have Spring use logback.